# For-loop code does not run after I add a second one

Tags: javascript, forms, for-loop, checkbox

I am doing a form that will send the data through email to Trello to create a card.
I am in the process to get the data from the different inputs, including checkboxes. I have different fieldsets with a group of checkboxes each. In the javascript function I did a for loop for the first fieldset and it worked. Then, I created a second for loop for the next group of checkboxes, but now the code does not run.
I am including the github repo.[my repo github link](https://github.com/eduartophoto/auw/blob/master/tech-form.js)

Comment: Please post relevant code here.

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?  Code does not run is not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check in line 9 you typed

```js
   var printers = document.getElementByName("printers[]");
```

instead you should add an 's' to

```js
 document.getElementsByName("priners[]");
```

Comment: Thanks Juan to point out that typo. I fixed it and now the email is coming up.